# Full reflective subcategories of CAT

Tags: ct.category-theory

This question was originally posted on [Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307558/full-reflective-subcategories-of-cat) but remains unanswered there.

**CAT** (considered there as a classical 1-category) is known to have plenty of full reflective subcategories: e.g. all discrete categories, all single-object categories, all groupoids, all thin categories, and intersections thereof, constitute such subcategories. Each of them, as well as many others, satisfies the following property: the reflection arrow for any non-empty category is surjective on objects. Does **CAT** have a full reflective subcategory that fails to satisfy this property?

The following is known about such subcategory, provided that it exists:

- it consists of gaunt categories (those that do not have non-identity isomorphisms)
- it contains at least one non-thin category
- it isn’t closed under the formation of full subcategories (i.e. contains a category some of whose full subcategories don’t belong to it)